# ¿how to build html <table> with [only] angular.js templates for a uncoherent json?

Tags: angularjs, templates

Im doing a template for angular.js 1.8 in a restricted app in which I cant build Constructors or use Javascript.

I need to show the data without tag it (I mean: I need to keep the original keys)

And I have data json like:

```
{
    "table": [
        {
            "name": "Teresa",
            "last_name": "Martinez"
        },
        {
            "name": "John",
            "last_name": "Wick"
        },
        {
            "name": "Json",
            "last_name": "Momoa",
            "Vehicle": "Dolphin"
        },
        {
            "name": "Javier",
            "last_name": "Teixidor",
            "Vehicle": "Van"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this environment and for this kind of tables when they are coherent I usually use an approaching like:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <th ng-repeat="(kh, vh) in data.table[0]">{{kh}}</th>

    <tr ng-repeat="v in data.table">
        <td ng-repeat="(kr, vr) in v">{{vr}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then I can show the data in a coherent json.

But ¿How to do it with unconsistent data, in the angular.js template, without controllers neither javascript, and without modify the original data?

I cant hardcode the "vehicle" key because maybe the first data of the list can have the 3 keys. Also the new keys don't always appear at the end of the document so I can't hardcode the th either.

And I cant use a json print because the real json is bigger than You can see here. (like more than 100 elements in the list)

Any Idea or suggest will be accepted :D

Thank You!

I expect and hope to solve a problem of uncoherent/unconsistent data only with angular.js 1.8 template is possible.

Currently I have a table like

```
<table>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <tr>
        <td>Teresa</td>
        <td>Martínez</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Wick</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Json</td>
        <td>Momoa</td>
        <td>Dolphin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Javier</td>
        <td>Teixidor</td>
        <td>Van</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```